# Why does Qt Creator 3.0.0 Welcome Mode not work in VM?

Tags: qt, virtual-machine, qt-creator, virtualbox

I originally installed Qt 5.20 with Qt Creator 3.0 on my Win7 64 bit machine and it worked flawlessly. Then I wanted to install it into a Win7 32 bit virtual machine (using VirtualBox). In the VM I start off on the qt-project.org site and download a version. I've tried both the `Qt Online Installer for Windows (13 MB) (Info)` link and the `Qt 5.2.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.8, OpenGL, 689 MB) (Info)` link. Both installs work and I can compile a simple Hello world demo. However, when Qt starts the Qt Welcome Mode is just a transparent window showing the contents of the desktop. If you change modes and go back to the Welcome mode it will then just show the contents of the previous mode. I would like to have access to the examples and tutorial links.

I'm using VirtualBox 4.3.6 and I have Guest Additions Installed. I'm running a copy of Win 7 Ultimate. The VM is very clean, it has Chrome installed, the latest Win updates and MS Security Essentials and that's about it. The virtual hard disk (vdi) has about 50 Gigabytes of free space after the install.

I've tried

```
1. turning off Windows Firewall and MS Security Essential real time protection. 
2. running as administrator.
3. running in xp SP2 and SP3, and win95 compatibility modes
4. running with Aero disabled
```

Nothing has helped. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I wondered the same thing, and figured it was a video driver bug. As it seems to be.

Comment: I downloaded a trial of VMWare and a it works correctly there under a Win7 32 bit VM. (Didn't try a 64 bit VM).

Comment: Strange thing as well: the default VGA Driver in Windows 7 displays the same issue. Not that that is a reference for anything...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I't a known bug. The Oracle Virtual Box has problems rendering the QML apps/widgets. And the welcome screen in QtCreator is a QML widget. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-34964

**Workaround**
Start QtCreator with `-noload Welcome` argument, and later in `Help > About Plugins...` menu disable "Welcome" for good.

Comment: I just installed it for Kubuntu on the same host and the Welcome mode works there. I did install explicitly some additional libraries

Comment: If you want this bug to get fixed, please login to their bug tracking system and vote for it!

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/43315), the solution is to do the following:

1. In Qt Creator, go to Help -> About Plugins...
2. Uncheck Qt Creator --> Welcome
3. Restart Qt Creator

Worked for me.

Comment: Well I could also just not click on the Welcome mode, but I want to use it for demoing the examples. At any rate I just stopped doing the demos in Virtual Box.