# How to run qt 5.5 app on WinXP

Tags: qt

I have a WinXP SP3 machine running. I got a fresh qt 5.5 out of the online installer. I'm trying to lauch some simple test application with QML 2.x but I get the following error while starting it :

```
"Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat bla-bla-bla...
Make sure that libEGL.dll, libGLESv2.dll and d3dcompiler_*.dll are available".
```

Well, I have `d3dcompiler_43.dll` at C:\WINDOWS\system32 ( after installing [DirectX Software Development Kit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812) ).

I also have `libEGL.dll` and `libGLESv2.dll` at C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin.

So what is the problem I'm facing?

BR,
Dmitry

Comment: try updating the graphic card drivers

Comment: as far as I understand libEGL.dll and libGLESv2.dll are intended to get rid of graphic driver dependencies...am I right?

Comment: not an expert, but they should rely on the graphic card drivers

Comment: winXP can be used with DirectX 9c latest...could be a problem here? What is the minimum version for qt 5.5 required?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-support.html   http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/supported-platforms.html#reference-configurations

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-issues.html

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't give any explanation for the problem I have

Comment: I can't give you further detail. Sorry about that. Probably others have a solution.. wait for them!

Comment: no problem, such kind of issues are rather tricky always. it's so sad that there is no backward compatibility for qt...to much efford for deployment

Comment: A similar issue has been discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704529/deploying-qt5-on-windows-without-hardware-acceleration

Comment: yes, I saw it, I have OpenGL 1.1 ... so is there any way to start qml 2.x with qt 5.5 on my PC?

Comment: Does your graphics card not support OpenGL 2 or above?

Comment: Well, of course I can install OpenGL 2.x on my PC. But what if I need to deploy my application on some PC which is not under my control...I should take care about all these details...seems not to be a convinient solution. I'd prefer to give an *.exe and *.dll-s...