# Qt Creator hangs in Ubuntu Virtualbox

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt-creator, virtualbox

I have a very weird problem. Ive got a an Ubuntu 14.04 running on VirtualBox 4.3.20 r96997. I installed QT Creator a while back and was working with it fine until today. Now when I try to start it, the screen is completely unresponsive, and it endes up freezing (just the QT Creator screen, ubuntu keeps working fine)

I have read in a couple of places that this could be because the welcome mode doesnt play nice with virtualbox 3d hardware acceleration:

[Why does Qt Creator 3.0.0 Welcome Mode not work in VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127335/why-does-qt-creator-3-0-0-welcome-mode-not-work-in-vm)

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/37412

But im starting ubuntu with the 3d hardware acceleration disabled, and Ive also tried starting it direcly from the terminal by going to the install folder and doing:

```
./qtcreator -noload Welcome -noload QmlDesigner -noload QmlProfiler
```

But it also freezes. And the weird thing is that it worked yesterday, and I havent installed any updates or changed the system, it just appears to have stopped working.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Try renaming its folder in the .config dir to reset it.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand. Which .config dir?

Comment: I think this question belongs to AskUbuntu.

Comment: @purplehuman it is not a ubuntu problem but a qt-creator problem on all linux flavours. Besides the guy did put the qt-creator tag :).

Comment: Indeed removing the .config/QtProject folder did the trick

Comment: @sashoalm that did indeed work. If you want put it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer, since OP confirmed it works.

Delete the configuration directory for QtCreator - [it's somewhere in ~/.config/](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6743019/492336)

Comment: Hi sashoalm, this is a pretty old thread, but I wanted to ask what directory you have deleted exactly. Is it the /home/XYZUser/.config/QtProject/qtcreator? Did you delete the whole folder or is there a configuration file that has to be deleted?

Comment: @FrozenTarzan See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742663/where-does-qtcreator-save-its-settings, the section about Linux. They say "On Linux and other Unix platforms, the files are located in ~/.config/QtProject and ~/.local/share/data/QtProject/qtcreator". Also, better rename them than delete so you can at least recover your settings them in case it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

In the ~/.config/QtProject folder is a lock file (QtCreator.ini.lock). This is the reason why QtCreator freezes. By removing only this file QtCreator will not freeze any more and all the configurations / settings are still there.

Answer (score 0):

Even with the current latest Qt Creator 6+, this issue happens when you compile a large project with some C++ header file changes. It happens even with few small consecutive compilations. **This issue persists even after closing the Qt Creator.**

Unfortunately there is no known fix yet, as it appears that Qt is spawning separate processes for threaded compilations. One may go to

> Projects > Builds & Run > [Desktop version] > Build > Build Steps >
> Make > Parallel jobs

Choose a smaller number such as 1 or 2. But this is not consistently helpful. To make the matter worse, sometimes it may make the compilation very slow.

Suppose, if this problem happens even after closing then there is a **workaround** for Ubuntu. Run below command after closing:

```
ps -ef | grep -i qt
```

This will list the processes still attached with the Qt Creator even after it was closed. Such as:

```
milind      1962    1759  0 07:25 ?        00:00:43 /home/milind/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator
milind      2669    1962  0 07:26 ?        00:00:00 /home/milind/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/../libexec/qtcreator/qtcreator_processlauncher /tmp/QtCreator-FXruRe/launcher-1962
milind      3588    2669  0 07:28 ?        00:00:27 /home/milind/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/libexec/qtcreator/clangbackend /tmp/QtCreator-FXruRe/ClangBackEnd-1962
milind     10772    5095  0 11:37 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i qt
```

Killing the topmost process kills all the subprocesses too.

> **kill -9 [pid]** // in above case it was 1962

Afterwards, opening the Qt Creator will feel like a stable and a new incarnation!

---

Source: From my [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1505714/22704) in AskUbuntu.